# Custom Taxonomy index/archive hierarchy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, archives, archive-template, register-taxonomy

I have built a custom taxonomy, say, cars. The URL looks like this: http://www.example.com/cars/elantra/ and this is working fine by using the file taxonomy-cars.php as the template.

Now, I would like for example to make an index page at http://www.example.com/cars/ which would show all the cars that I have created. However, this URL always returns me a 404 error. I have tried to set up archive.php, taxonomy.php and even cars.php according to multiple sources that I was able to find online but nothing seems to be working...

Someone said to add the has_archive argument to the taxonomy register call, however, this did not work either (and it seems to be aimed at post types and not taxonomies...)

So I would like how to achieve this in the current WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to create a page template and query all cars. Not sure if there is any other way.

Comment: I figured that much, but how do I make it so that http://www.example.com/cars/ go on this page template? I've tried using taxonomy.php, archive.php, cars.php and nothing works :/